# Inner fragment with fitsSystemWindows

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-statusbar, android-bottom-nav-view

I am working on the transparent status bar and bottom navigation bar visible. I have achieved the same with my last question: [Gradient status bar with BottomNavigationView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52639958/9514919)

> But now, I have a fragments in which `fitsSystemWindows` is not
>   working. I have layout like Activity -> Viewpager -> Fragments ->
>   Viewpager -> child Fragments.

I have gone through many attempts from stack overflow but still no luck :

1. [Appbar fitsSystemWindows - Inside a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40815997/8089770)
2. [Android - ViewPager fitsSystemWindows (fullscreen) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34513641/8089770)
3. [Setting a child view to fit system windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33573443/8089770)
4. [Android fitsSystemWindows not working when replacing fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39307674/8089770)
5. [How to apply gradient to status bar in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36907237/8089770)

I have added this **styles** :

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">false</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">false</item>
<item name="android:navigationBarColor">#000</item>
<item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

**In v21/style :**

```
 <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

In layout, I have added `fitsSystemWindows` to each fragment as well as activity.

**Activity layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">


    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <com.mobile.lendlease.views.WrapContentViewPagerBottomTab
                android:id="@+id/viewPagerContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_above="@+id/viewDivider"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/viewDivider"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1px"
                android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavigation"
                android:background="@color/default_border" />

            <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_12"
                android:paddingEnd="@dimen/margin_12"
                android:paddingStart="@dimen/margin_10"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/margin_10"
                app:itemBackground="@color/white"
                app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

**One of fragment layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorScreenBackground"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:elevation="0dp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_20"
                    android:background="@drawable/toolbar"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                    app:layout_scrollFlags="enterAlways"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/margin_18">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/ivHome"
                            android:layout_width="159dp"
                            android:layout_height="29dp"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"
                            android:src="@drawable/logo" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="end"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/ivSearch"
                                android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_47"
                                android:layout_height="32dp"
                                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/ivMall"
                                style="@style/notoSansSemiBoldStyle"
                                android:layout_width="58dp"
                                android:layout_height="32dp"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_18"
                                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin_10"
                                android:background="@drawable/search_bg_shape"
                                android:gravity="center"
                                android:text="@string/mall_all"
                                android:textAllCaps="false"
                                android:textColor="@color/gradient_card_color1"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/font_12"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@color/white"
                    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_indicator_line_selected"
                    app:tabGravity="center"
                    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/transparent"
                    app:tabMode="scrollable"
                    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorBlackLight"
                    app:tabTextAppearance="@style/themeTabText"
                    app:tabTextColor="@color/colorBlackLight" />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/viewPagerContainer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:focusable="false" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

</layout>
```

Comment: Have u try with `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` try inside `.CoordinatorLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`

Comment: @NileshRathod yes i have tried every possible attempts

Comment: r u using data binding??

Comment: @NileshRathod yes

Comment: set getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN); before setContentView() in oncreate